# table disappeared after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to show data after ajax call but it was disappeared after showing

**here is my code:**

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".medicine").keyup(function(){
                    var txt=$(this).val();
                    $.post("search.php",{medicine:txt},function(result){
                    $("#search-result").html(result);
                        });
                    });
        $(document).on('click','#find', function () {
           var input = $("#text").val();
           var url = 'row.php';
           var data = input;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {data:data},
                success: function (data) {
                    $(document).find('table').remove();
                    $("#temp_table").html(data);        
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

first function is for search bar which is working second one also working but when data comes in success function it show for a second in temporary div and vanished

Answer (score 0):

When your ajax completes, the `success` callback function removes all `<table>` elements caused by the use of the [*`.remove()`*](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function.

```
$(document).find('table').remove();
```

> Description: Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

---

If you want to **clear the html content** of your `<table>` elements **instead of removing them** (my guess), use `.empty()` instead

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: {
         data: data
     },
     success: function(data) {
         $('table').empty();
         $("#temp_table").html(data);
     }
 });
```